# MATLAB read formatted numbers from a file after a certain line

Tags: matlab, text, readfile

I have a file that contains arbitrary lines of characters/numbers. I need to extract formatted number after a certain line as follows:

```
Start of text file
Here is arbitrary lines of characters and numbers
  1 -100
  2 -200
...
ABC
1 2 3 
... 

Start extracting  the following formatted numbers after the blank line

                         10           1.5-04
                         20          -1.6-04
                        100           1.7-04
                        200           1.8-04
                        300          -1.9-04
                        400          -2.0-04

Stop reading when you find the previous blank line 
Then more arbitrary lines of characters and numbers 
    ABC
    1 2 3 
Then end of file
```

Using MATLAB, the question is how to extract the two columns of formatted numbers starting from (10           1.5-04) to (400          -2.0-04) after reaching the line that says "Start extracting  the following formatted numbers after the blank line."  Note the length of this column is not known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use `regex` to extract the numbers form your text, but I can't write a specific expression to extract the two columns because there is no such a text before and after these values can rely on.

```
clear 
text = fileread('test_file.txt');
pattern = '(?=(\s|-)[\d]+)(-|\s)[\d]+';
%pattern = '((\s|-)[\d]+)';
out = regexp(text, pattern,'match')
```

I hope my code gives you an idea ^-^

Answer (score 0):

(1) Read file line by line
(2) Find keyword to start reading after
(3) Read formatted number
(4) Leave file when done with formatted numbers

```
clc;close all; clear *
filename='Test.txt';
File = fopen(filename,'r');   
LineCont=0;                     %Line counter
Flag=0;                         %Flag to start extracting formatted numbers
st2='Start extracting the';     %Keyword

%Read file line by line
tline = fgetl(SGDFile);         %Read first line
while ischar(tline)
    Lcont=Lcont+1;              %Line number
    k = strfind(tline,st2);     %Check for keywork to start extracting 
    if ~isempty(k)              %Start extracting numbers
        Flag=1;                 %Flag to start reading formatted numbers
        Num=[];                 %Collect formatted numbers here
    end

    tline = fgetl(File);        %Move to next line
    if tline ~=-1               %If not empty
        if Flag==1
            value = strsplit(tline);            %Split numbers and text
            num= str2num(char(value))';         %Convert text to number
            if size(num,1)<1                    %Stop reading when blank
            break                               %Exit loop
            else                                
            Num=[Num;num];                      %Collect formatted numbers
            end  
        end
    end
end
fclose(File);
```

This might be an inefficient way of doing it, but it works.